# shell script for django VE causing deactivation of VE

Tags: django, bash

So I am trying this simple script which is essentially this (a full gist can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/sankhaMukherjee/6a2f0cb9f32cd5bfa81f7d373130871b)):

```
#!/bin/bash

virtualenv env

source ./env/bin/activate

pip install --upgrade pip 
pip install django

pip freeze > requirements.txt
django-admin startproject mysite .

git init
git config user.name "somename"
git config user.email "some-email@somedomain.com"

gitIgnore="
env/
*.pyc
"
echo '$gitIgnore' > .gitignore
git add .
git commit -a -m 'Initial commit'
```

After running the script I see that I am no longer within the virtual environment. Not sure why that is. I didn't `deactivate` at any point, so I would expect that I would still be in the `env` virtualenvironment.

Anyone can please shed some light on why my virtual environment is getting deactivated?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen. A script can't change the environment of its calling shell.

Comment: Or you can just call the script with `source`.  e.g., `source generateDjango.sh`

Comment: Oh! the source command works perfectly! Thanks!!